# Restore Weather App Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: weather

I seem to have deleted the weather app that came with my Galaxy S2 - is there an easy way to re-install it?

Comment: Factory reset, but you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: Aah - the old computer problem - little pink digit on end of hand causes disaster!  Thanks Al, I may try a factory reset simply because all sorts of enthusiastic 'helpers' have put a load of rubbish on my phone!

Comment: Was it an app or a widget? My S3 has a weather widget that has no associated app icon. Also, are you still using Touchwiz or are you using a different launcher? On my S3, the weather widget only shows up in Touchwiz, it doesn't show up in Nova Launcher.

Comment: It just appeared on the phone with no associated icon.  After a restart to solve a wi-fi problem the area it normally occupied was just a blank space ith a line around it and in trying to resolve the problem I deleted it.  It didn't matter which launcher I used the weather display appeared automatically.

Comment: Just a quick note - did a factory reset and it all went very easily.  I did backup to my Kies so everything was saved.  My message to anyone out there worrying about the reset - don't, just back up and all should be fine.  Weather widget now back!